# Get swf URL from AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I need to get URL of my SWF from ActionScript 3 in order to parse it (cannot use `loaderInfo.parameters`).

I've tried to use `root.loaderInfo.url` but it returns `null`. `FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.url` throws an error, because `topLevelApplication` doesn't exist. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you try to get `FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.url` after Application initialized?
ex) This doesn't work because this code try to get before Application initialized event.
`public var url:String = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.url;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, got it. As Yasuyuki Uno suggested in the comment, `url` property should be called after INIT event.

So I had

```
public function MyClass()
{
    root.loaderInfo.url;  // null
}
```

And it should be

```
import flash.events.Event;

public function MyClass()
{
    root.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, _onInit);
}

private function _onInit(ev:Event) : void
{
    root.loaderInfo.url;  // we have the URL now
}
```